# Typescript point to function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm writing a reactjs application using TypeScript and [redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux). To describe components props I'm using interfaces instead of `propTypes`. That allowes me to check prop types at compile time.

Some of the props are functions (redux action creators, wrapped by `connect` with `dispatch`).

How to say TypeScript that my component property is of that action creator function signature? I mean I don't want to repeat describing types.

To understand more the question, look at the example below:

```
// here is my action creator
function someAction(prop1: number, prop2: string) {
  ...
}

interface IComponentProps {
  // here I want to say
  // that this is the same function as above,
  // but I have to duplicate its type signature
  someAction(prop1: number, prop2: string);
}
```

Of course, I can create an interface for that function:

```
interface ISomeActionFunction {
  (prop1: number, prop2: string): void
}
```

and then use it in both function declaration and properties interface, but I wonder if there is any way to point to the specific function directly?

Comment: mmm, maybe you want something like `(arg:sometype, argb:SecondType)=>ReturnType`? So this expression can be used like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20a%3A%20(arga%3A%20String%2C%20argb%3A%20Number)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3D%20%20()%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aa(%22abs%22%2C%201)%3B)

Comment: You can try `someAction: typeof someAction` but I believe it's a bad practice. You should define the type twice or just not pass it as a prop.

Comment: I want that function to be linked to that property. So that when I change function signature in a precess of refactoring, the compiler would argue. Seems like it only could be done by creating interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already realised, using an interface is your best approach here. You can make it look like this:

```
interface IComponentProps {
    someAction: ISomeActionFunction;
}

interface ISomeActionFunction {
    (prop1: number, prop2: string): void;
}

const someAction: ISomeActionFunction = (p1, p2) => {
    // the compiler will correctly infer the types of p1 and p2 for you
    ...
}
```

This way, the function types are not repeated and the compiler can still check everything.

If you foresee a need for a lot of action creators, you can add a generic helper like this:

```
interface IBinaryActionCreator<T1, T2, TResult> {
  (prop1: T1, prop2: T2): TResult;
}

type ISomeActionFunction = IBinaryActionCreator<number, string, void>;
```

But that may be overkill.